# Testing a flatiron cli app with Mocha: app.log is undefined?

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, mocha.js, flatiron.js

I'm having problems testing a [flatiron](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron) [cli app](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/writing-cli-apps-with-flatiron) with [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/).

The command-line command I'd like to test creates a directory and logs success with app.log.info.

This is the code to be tested (./lib/commands/create.js):

```js
var flatiron = require('flatiron'),
  app = flatiron.app,
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

module.exports = function create(name, callback) {
  "use strict";
  fs.mkdir('./' + name);
  app.log.info('Directory created!');
}
```

This is the test (./test/create.js):

```js
var create = require('../lib/commands/create');

describe('Flatiron command', function () {
  "use strict";
  describe('#create()', function () {
    it('should create a directory ', function () {
      create('someDirectory');
      // check if the directory was created,
      // then remove the directory
    });
  });
});
```

`mocha test/log -R spec` gives me

```
  Flatiron command
    #log()
      1) should log something


  ✖ 1 of 1 tests failed:

  1) Flatiron command #create() should create a directory :
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'info' of undefined
```

Why is `app.log`not available to Mocha?

Is this because of how `function log`is exported?

Or has this something to do with how flatiron sets up the application? I tried requiring flatiron.app and starting it from the test like this

```js
var create = require('../lib/commands/create'),
  flatiron = require('flatiron'),
  app = flatiron.app;

describe('Flatiron command', function () {
  "use strict";
  describe('#create()', function () {
    it('should create a directory ', function () {
      app.start();
      create('someDirectory');
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

- but with no success, just a different error:

```
  Flatiron command
    #create()
      1) should create a directory


  ✖ 1 of 1 tests failed:

  1) Flatiron command #create() should create a directory :
     TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'start'
```

Or is this a case where you would use spies/stubs/mocks with something like [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to simulate the behavior of app.log somehow? Because I'm not really interested if the logging works, but if the directory is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got it.

Using `app.start()` was not quite it - but it works with `app.init()`.
In flatiron, `app.init()` is normally called from within the main file by plugging `flatiron.plugins.cli`into `app.use()` like this:

```
var flatiron = require('flatiron'), 
    path = require('path'), 
    app = flatiron.app; 

app.config.file({ file: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config.json') }); 

app.use(flatiron.plugins.cli, { 
  dir: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'commands'), 
  usage: 'Empty Flatiron Application, please fill out commands' 
}); 
app.start();
```

Calling `app.init()` [sets up logging](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron/blob/master/lib/flatiron/plugins/cli.js#L82) with [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston), the flatiron logging plugin.

But you can call `app.init()`from within the test without calling `app.start()` after it.
So this works:

```
var create = require('../lib/commands/create'),
  flatiron = require('flatiron'),
  app = flatiron.app;

describe('Flatiron command', function () {
  "use strict";
  describe('#create()', function () {
    it('should create a directory ', function () {
      app.init();
      create('someDirectory');
    });
  });
});
```

Mocha even takes care of the logging:

```
  Flatiron command
    #create()
      ◦ should create a directory : info: Directory created!
      ✓ should create a directory  (48ms)


  ✔ 1 tests complete (50ms)
```

If you want to stop the logging, you can use `app.log.loggers.default.remove(winston.transports.Console)`after you've called `app.init()`. You have to require winston to do this.

Comment: the #init() method comes from Broadway. You have to initialize Broadway apps to get the dependency injection features.